# Java HttpClient SSL:Failure initializing default SSL context

Tags: java, ssl

I'm trying to perform a http request. However, at the time of execution arises oshiyuka below. I suppose that it is impossible to create SSLContentFactory due to problems with the certificate. Who has ever seen such a thing?. JRE 1.5

```
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSchemeSocketFactory
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SocketFactory
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.LayeredSocketFactory 
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException 
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.X509HostnameVerifier
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier 
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AllowAllHostnameVerifier 
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.BrowserCompatHostnameVerifier 
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.ssl.StrictHostnameVerifier
Loaded class org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory 
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme 
Loaded class org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory

*** START APPLICATION TRACE ***

Defaultjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure initializing default SSL context

*** END APPLICATION TRACE ***
```

## Listing:

```
private static DefaultHttpClient createHttpClient()
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

    DefaultHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    defaultHttpClient.getParams().setParameter(
            ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

    defaultHttpClient = makeTrustfulHttpClient(defaultHttpClient);
    defaultHttpClient.addRequestInterceptor(
            new DiadocPreemptiveAuthRequestInterceptor(), 0);
    return defaultHttpClient;
}

private static DefaultHttpClient makeTrustfulHttpClient(HttpClient base)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {



    SSLSocketFactory ssf = getTrustfulSslSocketFactory();
    ClientConnectionManager ccm = base.getConnectionManager();
    ccm.getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 443, ssf));
    return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, base.getParams());
}

private static SSLSocketFactory getTrustfulSslSocketFactory()
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {


    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string)
                throws CertificateException {
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);


    return new SSLSocketFactory(ctx,
            SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);


}
```

Comment: Are you asking whether this error message has ever been seen before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10063882/failure-initializing-default-ssl-context

Comment: I saw this post. That's why I pointed JVM version. The problem is that SAP PI + EJB on a given JVM works fine. Because the built-in data exchange are limited, it was an attempt to create a custom development.
Is there still any solution to the problem? For example, by creating your Keystore with selfsigned keys?

Comment: To replicate your problem, it would be helpful if you included your main method and imports. I'm not sure what DiadocPreemptiveAuthRequestInterceptor is. Also, I don't know where the variable "proxy" is coming from in the createHttpClient method. Is it a class variable? EDIT: Actually, it would be preferable if you just keep the minimum amount of code in the main method that causes the error rather than posting the whole thing.

Comment: This is kind of a stretch, and I doubt it will help, but based on what I read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135230/difference-between-ssl-and-tls-and-their-usage-in-java, maybe you should use SSL instead of TLS.

Comment: ))))) This is not my code.... Sorry for my french, shit happened...

Comment: No, of course)))) TSL -> SSL don't work.

Comment: Look more to stack: Root Cause: java.security.KeyStoreException: problem accessing trust storejava.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: **PublicKey algorithm not implemented: ECPublicKey**

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. Are you saying that the code you posted is not the code that you wrote that causes the exceptions to be thrown?  I'm having a difficult time helping you because I don't know how or where your code crashed. What code are you running that makes the program throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
private SecureConnectionFactory makeSecureConnectionFactory()
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {


    return SecureConnectionFactory.getDefault();
}
```